# GraphType first schema endpoints using ListGraphType or using Connection

Tags: graphql, graphql-dotnet

I am setting up endpoints for 3 types (let's say Student, Classmate and Pet), where Student has many Classmates and many Pets.
I figured out 2 options:

- the first is to create a FriendsInterface and have Classmate and Pet implement that interface and then return them all as a ListGraphType
- the second is to create a Connection to those types: ClassmateConnection and PetConnection

What is the difference between the first and the second approach I described.

- Is it better to create a Connection (since I can see those allow for pagination in the API)?
- Does this second approach lead to having a better GraphQL schema, in which each GraphQL node is connected to the other by an edge.

I tried creating a ListGraphType since that is something I could see done in the examples.

However, there is no example on how to create a Connection and I keep running into the following error:

```
Error message:
Error: Request failed with status code 400
at e.exports (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:12:13653)
at e.exports (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:44:1280)
at XMLHttpRequest.p.onreadystatechange (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:12:12667)
```

First approach

```
public StudentType (MyData data) {
    Name = "Student";
    Description = "A curios creature in a giant universe.";

    Field (d => d.Id).Description ("The id of the student.");

    Field<ListGraphType<FriendInterface>> (
        "friends",
        resolve : context => data.GetFriends (context.Source)
    );
}
```

Second approach (creating Connections)

```
public StudentType (MyData data) {
    Name = "Student";
    Description = "A curios creature in a giant universe.";

    Field (d => d.Id).Description ("The id of the student.");

    Connection<ListGraphType<ClassmateType>> ()
        .Name ("classmates")
        .Description ("classmate test")
        .Resolve (context => data.GetClassmates (context.Source));

    Connection<ListGraphType<PetType>> ()
        .Name ("classmates")
        .Description ("pet test")
        .Resolve (context => data.GetPets (context.Source));
}

public ClassmateType (MyData data) {
    Name = "Classmate";
    Description = "A misunderstood creature in a giant universe.";

    Field (d => d.Id).Description ("The id of the classmate.");
}

public PetType (MyData data) {
    Name = "Pet";
    Description = "An animal creature in a giant universe.";

    Field (d => d.Id).Description ("The id of the pet.");
}
```

In the first approach, this is the query I want to send:

```
student(studentID: "1") {
    id
    name
    friends {
        id
    }
}
```

In the second approach, the query is as follows:

```
 student(studentID: "1") {
    id
    name
    classmateConnection {
        classmates {
            id
        }
    }
    petConnection {
        pets {
            id
        }
    }
}
```